# Sequentially Splitting the load on a Parallel.Foreach Loop

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I have a million elements in a List to process.
Dropping them crudely into a *Parallel.ForEach* would just saturate the CPU.
Instead I split the Elements Master Lists into pieces and drop the Sublists into a parallel loop.

```
List<Element> MasterList = new List<Element>();
Populate(MasterList); // puts a Million elements into list;

//Split Master List into 100 Lists of 10.0000 elements each
List<List<Element>> ListOfSubLists = Split(MasterList,100);

foreach (List<Element> EL in ListOfSubLists )
{
   Parallel.ForEach(EL, E =>
   {
     // Do Stuff
   }

  //wait for all parallel iterations to end before continuing   
}
```

What is the best way for waiting for all parallel iteration to end before continuing to next iteration of the upper loop ?

**Edit :** 
as some answers stated, "saturate the CPU" is not an accurate expression. 
Actually I just want to limit the CPU usage, and avoid excessive load on it coming from this processing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Parallel.ForEach` will not saturate the CPU; it uses some intelligence to decide how many parallel threads to run simultaneously, with a max of 63.

See: [Does Parallel.ForEach limits the number of active threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114317/does-parallel-foreach-limits-the-number-of-active-threads)

You can also set the max degree of parallelism if you want, by supplying a `ParallelOptions` like `new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 }` as the second argument to `Parallel.ForEach`.

As a last point, `Parallel.ForEach` blocks until all of the iterations have completed. So your code, as written, works. You do not need to wait for the iterations to complete.

Comment: I concur.  Parallel.foreach enumerating 10,000 items won't create any more/less threads than a million.  If RAM becomes an issue dealing with your million items, then consider BlockingCollection<T> -- this will limit the number of items you have in memory at any one time.

Comment: Thank you. As of the last sentence, I did not know that Parallel.ForEach was blocking. Very good to know. For CPU Saturation, See edit.

Comment: @MikaJacobi If you wanted nonblocking for some reason, you'd have to do it yourself by spawning new `Task`.

Comment: @Ragoczy: BlockingCollection is very interesting. It will be very useful to me indeed. A million thread is to much as the "Do Stuff" part is time-&-memory consuming that's why I wanted to limit it

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean "Saturate the CPU"

You can still throttle the Parallel foreach loop by supplying it with `ParallelOptions`
One property of which is a `MaxDegreesOfParallelism`

That will allow you to go back to your single collection e.g.

```
Parallel.ForEach(
     collection,
     new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5},
     E => { DoStuff(E) }
);
```

Comment: Thank you, very useful to know. I was not aware of that. See edit.