# C# Split List<T> into groups using TPL Parallel ForEach

Tags: c#, split, parallel-processing, thread-safety, task-parallel-library

I need to process a `List<T>` of thousands of elements.

First I need to group the elements by year and type, so I obtain a `List<List<T>>`. Then for each internal `List<T>` I want to add objects of type T until the max package size is reached for the `List<T>`, then I create a new package and go on the same way.

**I want to use `Parallel.ForEach` loop.**

My actual implementation works well if I run it sequentially, but **the logic is not Thread Safe and I want to change it.**
I think the problem is on the inner `Parallel.ForEach` loop, when the max size for the `List<T>` is reached and I instantiate a new `List<T>` inside the same reference.

```
private ConcurrentBag<ConcurrentBag<DumpDocument>> InitializePackages()
{
    // Group by Type and Year
    ConcurrentBag<ConcurrentBag<DumpDocument>> groups = new ConcurrentBag<ConcurrentBag<DumpDocument>>(Dump.DumpDocuments.GroupBy(d => new { d.Type, d.Year })
        .Select(g => new ConcurrentBag<DumpDocument> (g.ToList()))
        .ToList());

    // Documents lists with max package dimension
    ConcurrentBag<ConcurrentBag<DumpDocument>> documentGroups = new ConcurrentBag<ConcurrentBag<DumpDocument>>();

    foreach (ConcurrentBag<DumpDocument> group in groups)
    {       
        long currentPackageSize = 0;

        ConcurrentBag<DumpDocument> documentGroup = new ConcurrentBag<DumpDocument>();

        ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Parameters.MaxDegreeOfParallelism };
        Parallel.ForEach(group, options, new Action<DumpDocument, ParallelLoopState>((DumpDocument document, ParallelLoopState state) =>
            {
                long currentDocumentSize = new FileInfo(document.FilePath).Length;

                // If MaxPackageSize = 0 then no splitting to apply and the process works well
                if (Parameters.MaxPackageSize > 0 && currentPackageSize + currentDocumentSize > Parameters.MaxPackageSize)
                {
                    documentGroups.Add(documentGroup);

                    // Here's the problem!
                    documentGroup = new ConcurrentBag<DumpDocument>();

                    currentPackageSize = 0;
                }

                documentGroup.Add(document);
                currentPackageSize += currentDocumentSize;
            }));

        if (documentGroup.Count > 0)
            documentGroups.Add(documentGroup);
    }

    return documentGroups;
}

public class DumpDocument
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public long Type { get; set; }
    public string MimeType { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
}
```

Since my operation is quite simple, actually I only need to get the file size using:

```
long currentDocumentSize = new FileInfo(document.FilePath).Length;
```

I read around that I can also use a `Partitioner`, but I've never used that and anyway it's not my priority at the moment.

I also already read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362573/sequentially-splitting-the-load-on-a-parallel-foreach-loop) that is similar but doesn't solve my problem with the inner loop.

**UPDATE 28/12/2016**

I updated the code to meet verification requirements.

Comment: Are you just trying to speed things up with parallelism?

Comment: In this specific case, yes. I want to speed up the initialization of packages. Then each single package (ConcurrentBag<DumpDocument>) pass through a more complex Parallel ForEach loop that process the documents.

Comment: It seems to me that you have an in-memory list. It will almost always be faster to process the data on one thread rather than in parallel. It's only if you have some heavy processing that it is worth doing anything in parallel.

Comment: Ok. But what if I need to do something more complicated inside the loop? How can I make my code Thread Safe? That is my question...

Comment: Sure. Can you modify your code so that it is a [mcve]? Then it can be answered.

Comment: @Enigmativity Hi! A little bit late, but I updated to code by adding the referenced class `DumpDocument`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the code update it seems that you'are using the `ConcurrentBag` so the is another non-thread-safe logic left in your code:

```
long currentPackageSize = 0;
if (// .. && 
    currentPackageSize + currentDocumentSize > Parameters.MaxPackageSize
// ...
{
    // ...
    currentPackageSize += currentDocumentSize;
}
```

`+=` operator isn't atomic, and you'll definitely have a race condition there, and reading the value of a `long` variable isn't thread-safe here. You may introduce the `locks` there, or to use the [`Interlocked` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x629ff68.aspx) to atomically update the value:

```
Interlocked.Add(ref currentPackageSize, currentDocumentSize);
Interlocked.Exchange(ref currentPackageSize, 0);
Interlocked.Read(ref currentPackageSize);
```

Using this class will lead for a some refactoring code (I think that usage of `CAS` operations such as `CompareExchange` is more preferable in your case), so, maybe for you it is easiest way to use the locks. You probably should implement both ways and test them and measure the execution time).

Also, as you can see, the instantiation isn't thread-safe too, so you had to either lock the variable (which will lead to thread synchronization pause) or refactor your code to two-steps: at first you get all the file sizes in parallel, after that you iterate over results in sequential manner, avoiding race conditions.

As for the `Partitioner`, you shouldn't use this class here, as it's usually being used to schedule the work across the CPU, not to split the results.

However, I'd like to note that you have some minor code issues:

1. You can remove `ToList()` calls inside the constructors of the `ConcurrentBag` because it accepts the `IEnumerable`, which you already have:

   ```
   ConcurrentBag<ConcurrentBag<DumpDocument>> groups = new ConcurrentBag<ConcurrentBag<DumpDocument>>(Dump.DumpDocuments.GroupBy(d => new { d.Type, d.Year })
       .Select(g => new ConcurrentBag<DumpDocument> (g)));
   ```

   This will help you to avoid unnecessary copies of your grouped data
2. You can use the `var` keyword to avoid the duplication of the types in your code (this is just a sample line, you can change it many times across your code):

   ```
   foreach (var group in groups)
   ```
3. You should not use maximum degree of parallelism unless you're knowing what you're doing (and I think that you aren't):

   ```
   var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Parameters.MaxDegreeOfParallelism };
   ```

   `TPL` default task scheduler tries to adjust the thread pool and CPU usage for your tasks, so in general this number should be equal to `Environment.ProcessorCount`.
4. You can use `lambda` syntax for the `Parallel.ForEach`, and do not create a new `Action` (you can also move out this code to a method routine):

   ```
   (document, state) =>
   {
       long currentDocumentSize = new FileInfo(document.FilePath).Length;

       // If MaxPackageSize = 0 then no splitting to apply and the process works well
       if (Parameters.MaxPackageSize > 0 && currentPackageSize + currentDocumentSize > Parameters.MaxPackageSize)
       {
           documentGroups.Add(documentGroup);

           // Here's the problem!
           documentGroup = new ConcurrentBag<DumpDocument>();

           currentPackageSize = 0;
       }

       documentGroup.Add(document);
       currentPackageSize += currentDocumentSize;
   }
   ```

   The lambda is correctly compiled because you already have a generic collection (a bag), and there is an overload which accepts the `ParallelLoopState` as a second parameter.

Comment: Thank you! I finally refactored the code in 2 steps. But I also appreciated your excursus of the Interlocked class. I used it on some other ParallelForEach blocks in my code, expecially for counters.

Comment: You're welcome:) Yeah, for counters such increments are very helpful. Good luck with your projects.