# parallel.for or task.startnew in multithreading process

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, task-parallel-library, taskfactory

I have a list of strings that I need to pass to a process in a different class. What I want to know which of the two ideas would be a better approach to use in terms of speed, efficiency and parallel processing. The list contains +- 10000 strings and I want to limit the threads appropriately to have only about 5threads running at one time:

```
For i as integer = 0 to searchPages.Count - 1
    Parallel.For(0,10,Sub(x)
                        ps.processPage(searchPages.Item(i))
                 End Sub)
Next
```

The task factory seems to work fine but not sure which to implement.

```
For i as integer = 0 to searchPages.Count - 1
    Dim fact as Task=Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() ps.processPage(searchPages.Item(i)))
    If i = 11 then
           Tasks.Task.WaitAll()
    Endif

Next
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this type of pure data parallelism, I would recommend using `Parallel.ForEach`:

```
Parallel.ForEach(searchPages, Sub(page) ps.processPage(page))
```

If you want to restrict this to use 5 threads, you can do that via [ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx):

```
Dim po as New ParallelOptions
po.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5
Parallel.ForEach(searchPages, po, Sub(page) ps.processPage(page))
```

This will have less overhead than `Task.Factory.StartNew`, since the partitioning within the `Parallel` class will reuse Tasks, and prevent over scheduling from occurring.  It will also use the current thread for some of the processing instead of forcing it into a wait state, which also will reduce the total overhead involved.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I wouldn't worry too much about how many threads are being used (unless you can show it's a problem). Just use a `Parallel.ForEach` and let the runtime work out the optimum number of threads.

Take a look at the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114317/does-parallel-foreach-limits-the-number-of-active-threads) question for some good details on how the threads are managed by the runtime for you.