# Parallel.ForEach() - How many threads?

Tags: .net, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I am downloading files which means that even though I had only 2 cores, it would improve performance to make more than two threads.

Does the `Parallel.ForEach()` only make as many threads as the amount of cores, 
even though I set ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism to a higher value?

Comment: What version of .NEt are you using? ReadAsync might be a lot easier if you are on .NET4.5

Comment: I am using 4.0. But I can ask if we can install 4.5 on the servers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Parallel.ForEach limits the number of active threads?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114317/does-parallel-foreach-limits-the-number-of-active-threads)

Comment: Your answer is in that post, and it was answered by @JonSkeet.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. What do you do with a duplicate? Delete it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From documentation:

> The MaxDegreeOfParallelism limits the number of concurrent operations
>   run by Parallel method calls that are passed this ParallelOptions
>   instance to the set value, if it is positive. If
>   MaxDegreeOfParallelism is -1, then there is no limit placed on the
>   number of concurrently running operations.

This function throw only `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` and type of `MaxDegreeOfParalleism` is int. So it means, that it can create more threads than count of cores.

I can confirm it, because I've ran a lot of xml generation processes and Task Manager shown count of processes exactly as I've set before.