# Force code to run on multiple cores

Tags: c#, .net, windows, multithreading, affinity

I was surprised that `Parallel` doesn't consume all threads. I write this code:

```
public static long Sum(this IList<long> list)
{
    long result = 0;
    Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(0, list.Count),
        () => 0L,
        (range, state, sum) => Sum(list, range),
        x =>
        {
            Interlocked.Add(ref result, x);
        });
    return result;
}
```

then I try to use this one:

```
long res = list.AsParallel().Sum();
```

but it consume single core too.

Question: how can I force to run this code in multiple threads, by setting process affinity or something else, I guess, there is some technique to do it.

Comment: try it without the partitioner?

Comment: I'd say summing up a list of long is something you should parallelize in the first place... you get additional overhead per thread created... also a thread != a core... a core can / and does run a lot of threads... try a much bigger list...

Comment: How did you know it just uses single core? I just tried `Enumerable.Range(1,int.MaxValue).AsParallel().Count();` it uses all of the cores (8 in my case).

Comment: Since you're synchronizing on every 'add' you are killing the performance anyway.

Also - I've just tried summing the biggest list I could create in memory, and it took 40ms - without any parallelism - is this worth doing?

Comment: @DaveBish I tried to do it parallel and could not get faster

Comment: Theres just not enough beef in the task to get parallelism to improve performance...

Comment: @DaveBish where do you see synchronizing on every 'add'? `Interlocked` is only used in `finally` block...

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I opened task manager and saw only one core 100% load

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy - Quite right - my mistake. Regardless - I don't think this is a great case for parallelism - as the overheads of doing such, are probably greater that the operation itself

Comment: @DaveBish well, I get same results, multithreading overhead eats all benefits from parallelism, but I believe it's because it doesn't consume enough threads. I know that performance is not a big problem here, but anyway info about forcing execution be done on all cores should be helpful while implementing others LINQ methods. So this is 2 main reasons why I want to make it work faster.

Comment: They key point is that using 'Task' based Parallelism never guarantees multi-thread execution - it just allows it, based upon internal framework rules. If you ever *need* to have multi-core work done, you are best-off using the 'Thread' object, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: This is a default behaviour for `Parallel` class, as there is no direct connction between active threads and performance.

Comment: See also: [1000 threads](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1114317/213550), [Parallel Loops](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963552.aspx)

Comment: @DaveBish and It's pretty curious that people upvote your comment about `killing the performance` without examining if it's true or not. And that question is marked as duplicate when it isn't, while "why he isn't running" is not equals to "how to force it running". I only hope that CLR knows situation better than me and additional threads won't speed up the code.

Comment: Not *strictly* a duplicate, I suppose, but close enough IMO.  The literal answer to this question is "you can't" which is not very interesting.